# Converting a list containing a single number into an integer

Tags: python

I have a line of programming which gives me a list that looks like this:

```
a=[4]
```

I want to add the single number in that list to another number which is calculated earlier
for example

```
y=8-2
Answer=a+y
print Answer
```

However, it will not allow me to do this, saying that a list and an integer are not compatiable

I would like to know, how would I change

```
a=[4]
```

into

```
a=4
```

or in other words, turning list a containing a single number into an integer

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get the number out with `a[0]`.

```
a = a[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = a[0]
```

This will fetch the first element from list `a` and assign to num.. Thus `num` will contain an `integer` value `4` in your case..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @BrenBarn's answer, note that if you're certain that the "line of programming" you have is something like a function call:

```
a = SomeFunction()
```

that returns the list, you can do the indexing right there so that the list is never stored in `a`:

```
a = SomeFunction()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn a list containing a single number into an integer do:

```
a=[4.5] # imagine you have number, but it's of type float
if len(a) == 1:
    aa=int(a[0]) #

print aa
4
```

Note that this will exclude lists that contain more than one element. If you always want to access the first element, just do it by index as suggested in other answers.

Comment: Why would you use factory when you are explicitly adding an integer to your list.. I think in this case you are pretty sure taht its an integer..  Also, no need of that length check..\

Comment: If you don't know the how many elements your list has? OP asked for turning a number into an integer also.

Comment: @larsvegas.. Problem is absolutely fine.. No problem with it.. But, it would have been better if you took:  -`a = [4.5]` if you using factory